# Strange problem with crontab and echo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface, cron, echo

```
$ echo -e "test1\ntest2" > logfile

$ echo -e "test1\ntest2" >> logfile

$ cat logfile
test1
test2
test1
test2

$ rm logfile

$ crontab -e
* * * * * echo -e "test1\ntest2" >> logfile

$ sleep 160

$ cat logfile
-e test1
test2
-e test1
test2
```

Why am I getting the `-e` in the output? Both crontab and bash are using `/bin/echo`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're probably *not* both using `/bin/echo`.  The environment used by `cron` is probably different from your interactive environment.  Specify the full path to be sure.

Comment: well, before I tried this test, I tried another test: `* * * * * which echo > logfile` -- it showed the same thing as `which echo`

Comment: ...but specifying the full path as you suggest does fix the problem. Strange?!

Comment: aidan: "which" doesn't search for shell built-ins, it looks for files under $PATH. That's why "which echo" shows identical results, and that's why the interactive environment and cron can differ.

Comment: Golden rule of crons: Always use full paths.  If you always follow the rule, you won't get something unexpected or borken.

Comment: `type echo` should provide you some clarity here :)

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the reasons people recommend using `printf` instead of `echo` for portability.

```
* * * * * printf "test1\ntest2\n" >> logfile
```

The shell that `cron` uses is `sh` rather than Bash. On my system, `sh` is really Dash and its `echo` doesn't have `-e`. So `-e` becomes just another string to be output. Other versions of the Bourne shell or shells that provide its functionality may have `-e`.

If you use `echo` without the full path in your `crontab`, you're getting the shell's builtin `echo` instead of `/bin/echo`. On the command line, if you're using Bash, then `echo` without the full path gives you Bash's builtin version.